# Json Data Reordering After Parsing Objective- C

Tags: objective-c

Hi I am using a php api in my ios app and I want the result in an  **Specific order** . It gives the correct order if i parse it in browser by online tools.But as I am using **NsJsonSerialisation** to Parse it into any of foundation object I am getting reordered list of data.The Order is not Alphabetic,So I am unable to make it at my end.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a specific order, you need to use a JSON array:

```
[
    "one",
    "two",
    "three"
]
```

instead of a JSON object.

The elements in a JSON object have not fixed order. And a JSON object becomes a `NSDictionary` instance in Objective-C, whose elements have no order either.

Comment: Yes, I think @Codo has given the answer. You must be using a Dictionary. You should use an Array instead. Please show us your JSON for further proof.

Comment: Means I have to get the result in Array?

Comment: Yes, it must be produced with an array instead of an object in the first place. And then you have to use a *NSArray* instead of an *NSDictionary* instance in Objective-C.

Comment: by using an nsarray it gives the same unordered result.What should I do now?

Comment: You have to fix it mainly where the JSON is generated in the first place, i.e. probably on the server side.